# jQuery - Determine user vs programmatic event

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` and I handle `change()` event.  When the user changes the select option I want to perform a series of actions.  But, if I trigger the change via `$(item).trigger('change')` then I do not want to perform said series of actions.

I see [`trigger()` contains](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) an overload with parameters.  I'm not sure if this will work as I have not written a custom event.  So, what should I do to determine the difference between a user fired event and my programmatic fired event?

Comment: hmm...why trigger the event? Must be some side-effect you're looking for? Is there change handler code that needs to run regardless of user vs programmatic?

Comment: @dotjoe - kinda a lot to explain.  Basically I'm making a website behave like a desktop application.  I need to trigger events in a certain order in order to avoid race conditions with my $.get() requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty way to do it:

```
var progChange = false;

$('select').change(function() {
    if (!progChange) {
        // Do user actions...            
    }
    progChange = false;
});

function callSelectChange() {
    progChange = true;
    $('select').change();
}
```

You can do it with the `trigger` method in essentially the same way, and it would eliminate the global, which is a good thing:

```
$('select').change(function(event, progChange) {
    if (!progChange) {
        // Do user actions...
    }
});

$('select').trigger('change', [true]);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/XsPc5/

Comment: You can use $('select').data('progchange') instead of a global variable. Also, I don't see why you set progChange to false inside the if block. If it is executing, it is already false.

Comment: Yes, the globals are bad as what happens when this type of event happens on 2 different nodes?

Comment: It's called quick-and-dirty for a reason. The second method is definitely the better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this normally, but, you can fake it by passing a flag from your programmtic call.

```
$('.selector').bind('click', function(event,data) {
    if(typeof(data.programmatic) === 'undefined') {
        //Do user stuff here
    } else {
        //Do progammatic stuff here
    }
});

//Call programmitcally
$('.selector').trigger('click',{programmatic:true});
```

Comment: +1 - This is a good answer.  I chose the other answer simply because I find the .change() easier to read than the .bind() method.  I did not use a global variable.

Comment: Benefit to bind is you can setup multiple events or custom events. For example: `$('.selector').bind({click:function(){...},change:function(){...},mouseover:function(){...}})` or `$('.selector').bind('myEvent',function(){...});`.  The other is simply a shorthand way of using bind, which actually calls bind.  Whichever you prefer or like is best of course :)